# How to resize / expand a matrix by adding zeros?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

How is it possible to expand a quadratic - let's say NxN - matrix to a bigger on like a (N+k)x(N+k) matrix?

It's really all about resizing the matrix and filling the missing rows/columns with zeros such that not dimension mismatch occurs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can add zeros to a matrix using [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html)... For example:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4];
B = padarray(A,[2 2],'post')

B =
 1     2     0     0
 3     4     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
```

Or, if you don't have the image processing toolbox, you can use matrix indexing:

```
B = zeros(size(A)+k, class(A));
B(k:end-k+1,k:end-k+1) = A;
```

Answer (score 9):

No need to do it more difficult than it is. MATLAB automatically pads with zeros if you assign something to an element outside of the original size:

```
n = 4;
A = [1 2; 3 4];
A(n,n) = 0;
A =    
   1   2   0   0
   3   4   0   0
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks for that one! But I choose natans answer since padarray() seems to offer more functionality. But +1 for a simpler but smaller solution :)